# Non-isotrivial fibration with vanishing Kodaira–Spencer map at a singular point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to C$ be a non-isotrivial family of elliptic curves over a curve $C$ (for simplicity, you may assume it is just the projective line over complex number field) with singular locus $D\subset C$. Consider the logarithmic Kodaira–Spencer map
$$\theta\colon E^{10}\rightarrow E^{01}\otimes \Omega_{C}^1(\log D).$$

**Question:** Recall the KS map is the differential of the corresponding moduli map, so it is easy to describe the vanishing locus of KS map in $C-D$. My question is how to determine the vanishing locus of KS map in $D$. I.e. how to find those $x\in D$ such that the map $\theta$ vanishes at $x$.

Comment: If the fiber has a single ordinary double point, then vanishing of the Kodaira-Spencer map is equivalent to non-regularity of the total scheme at the double point.

Comment: Jason, I am not sure if I understand. Here I always assume the surface $X$ and the base curve $C$ are regular schemes. Do you means: if the singular fiber at $x$ is of type $I_1$, then the KS map doesn't vanish at $x$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asserting.  The Kodaira-Spencer map for the elliptic fibration factors the "Kodaira-Spencer map" for deformations of the singularity of the singular fiber.  The regularity hypothesis is equivalent to nonvanishing of the second Kodaira-Spencer map, and this then implies nonvanishing of the original Kodaira-Spencer map.

Comment: I am relatively new to deformations of the singularity, could you explain a little more about KS map for deformations of the singularity? Why the regularity hypothesis is equivalent to the nonvanishing? I agree with your asserting. It also holds for type $I_v$ and $I_v^*$ ($v\geq1$), this is due to the fact that the monodromy around the point is not finite. I care most about other types. I.e. types $II$  $III$  $IV$ $I_0^*$ $IV^*$ $III^*$ $II^*$.

Comment: What do you already know, and what are you willing to read?  It is a feature (bug?) of deformation theory that there are many different formalisms that establish the same basic results, and many authors are unwilling to translate from one formalism to another.  Probably the simplest approach is just to consider when the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[x,y,t]]/\langle xy-t^r\rangle$ is a regular local ring.  That will convince you that the assertion I claimed is true, and then you can track down references that agree with your own formalism.